# How to plot a Moving Average Line starting from 3PM to 3:30PM on TradingView?

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api

Indian Stock market averages the closing price of each 1 minute candle for the last 30 minutes. It is this moving average starting from 3PM and moving till 330PM that's used in options pricing, how do I draw that line on Trading View?

At 3:01PM, closing price of 3PM is the average

At 3:02PM, closing price of 3PM & 3:01 is averaged

At 3:03PM, closing price of 3PM, 3:01 & 3:02 is averaged

and continues so on, adding new minute close price to the sum and averaging.

any simple and elegant way to do this?

I'm testing time() and timestamp() functions

using a 30 min sma on 1 minute timeframe becomes accurate only at the end of 330PM, it is useless by then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing there are few ways to achieve this. I would use an `array` that I should populate with `close` price only if the bar is in session (or clear the `array` if not in session). Then I would average the array:

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay = true)

session = input.session("1500-1530", title="Trading Times")

in_session(session_times) =>
    not na(time(timeframe.period, session_times))

var avg_array = array.new_float()

if in_session(session)
    array.push(avg_array, close)
else
    array.clear(avg_array)

plot(array.avg(avg_array), style = plot.style_linebr)
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked perfectly, I didn't understand this part of the code "in_session(session_times) =>
    not na(time(timeframe.period, session_times))" , rest was straightforward.  Thanks again, I had been looking for this piece of code for a long long time, Really appreciate your help.

Comment: `time(timeframe.period, session_times)` will return the UNIX time of the current bar for the timeframe and session (as we declared in the variable `session_times`) or `na` if the time point is out of session. So if we'll check when this function returns a non `na` value, then we know the bar is inside the session we have stated. Since the `na(x)` function returns `true` when `x` is `na`, we can check if `x` has a non `na` value using `not na(x). In our case, `x` will be `time(timeframe.period, session_times)`

Comment: Thank you very much, you have been immensely helpful :)